# Drawing a an array of rectangles on the screen using kivy language in python file

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to draw a array of rectangles, which could be dynamically changed (that's something not implemented yet).

The expected behavior is having a orange rectangle all along the top of the screen (for future add some labels), and then the array of rectangles blue and green.
But instead the top orange rectangle doesn't show and the array of green and blue displays only in the 100x100 canvas with a weird extension on the edges.

Any advice?

[image]

Python file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.properties import ListProperty, NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class cell(Widget):
    color = ListProperty([1, 1, 1, 1])

    def __init__(self, number, **kwargs):
        super(cell, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.number = number
        self.update_color()

    def update_color(self):
        if self.number == 1:
            self.color = (0, 1, 0, 1)
        else:
            self.color = (0, 0, 1, 1)

    def resize(self, pos, size):
        self.pos = pos
        self.size = size


class game_screen(Screen):
    neighbors = [(0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0), (1, -1), (0, -1), (-1, -1), (-1, 0), (-1, 1)]

    screen_width = NumericProperty(0)
    screen_height = NumericProperty(0)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(game_screen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.x_size = 5
        self.y_size = 7
        self.world = self.new_world(self.x_size, self.y_size)
        self.resize(self.world)

    def new_world(self, x, y):
        world = [["" for i in range(y)] for j in range(x)]
        return world

    def resize(self, world):
        self.cell_size = (self.screen_width / self.x_size, self.screen_height / self.y_size)

        main_layout = BoxLayout(size=self.size, orientation='vertical')
        top_info = RelativeLayout(size_hint=(1, None), size=(self.width, dp(50)))
        with self.canvas:
            Color(1, .5, 0, 1)
            self.rect= Rectangle(size=(self.width, self.height), pos=self.pos)
            self.bind(pos=self.update_rect,
                      size=self.update_rect)
        main_layout.add_widget(top_info)
        world_layout = RelativeLayout(size=self.size)
        for i in range(len(world)):
            for j in range(len(world[0])):
                print (f'x:{i}, y:{j}')
                num = i + j
                if num % 2 == 0:
                    numero = 1
                else:
                    numero = 0
                position = (self.cell_size[0] * i, self.cell_size[1] * j)
                celula = cell(numero)
                celula.update_color()
                celula.resize(pos=position, size=self.cell_size)
                world[i][j] = celula
                world_layout.add_widget(celula)
        main_layout.add_widget(world_layout)
        self.add_widget(main_layout)

    def update_rect(self, *args):
        self.rect.pos = (0, self.height-dp(50))
        self.rect.size = (self.width, dp(50))


Builder.load_file("CellWorld.kv")


class GameOfLifeApp(App):
    sm = None
    def build(self):
        self.sm = ScreenManager()
        self.sm.add_widget(game_screen(name="game"))
        return self.sm


GameOfLifeApp().run()
```

Kivy file, honestly I'm not really sure I need 'screen_width' and 'screen_height'. I was using it for testing solutions I found on other codes while trying to solve this issue.

```
<game_screen>:
    screen_width: self.width
    screen_height: self.height

<cell>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: self.color
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```

Comment: Did you try with `GridLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout` as your `world_layout` (as there's a grid like structure) ? It will be much more manageable.

Comment: I haven't tried the GridLayout. It could be a solution. But the main reason to stick with the RelativeLayout is to have better understanding on managing the rectangle drawing, which is being a struggle in general on several test I have been doing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the size that you set for your `Cell` widgets is being ignored, because `size_hint` takes precedence over `size`. Just add `size_hint: None, None` to your `kv` in the `<Cell>:` rule:

```
<cell>:
    size_hint: None, None
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: self.color
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```

You should also delay calling the `resize()` method until the `game_screen` gets its size set. You can use `Clock.schedule_once()` to accomplish this. First remove `self.resize(self.world)` from the `game_screen` `__init__()` method, Then add the `Clock.schedule_once()` call to the `build()` method:

```
def build(self):
    self.sm = ScreenManager()
    gs = game_screen(name="game")
    self.sm.add_widget(gs)
    Clock.schedule_once(partial(gs.resize, gs.world))
    return self.sm
```

And modify the signature of `resize()` to handle the extra arg added by the `Clock.schedule_once()`:

```
def resize(self, world, *args):
```

Comment: By doing this, the cells at the edges don't extend weirdly as before. But everything is contained in just a 100x100 square at the bottom left.

Comment: That is because you are calling `resize()` from the `__init__()` method, before the `size` of the `game_screen` is set (it is still at the default of `(100,100)`. See updated answer.

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot. I make some modifications on the code in order to no need to use the clock and I just concatenate some. it seems finally working correctly.